# undefined symbols when linking one .so with other

Tags: c, linux, gcc, shared-libraries

`a.so` defines function `A()`, `b.so` defines function `B()` and calls `A()` that is defined in `a.so`. `b.so` is linked to `a.so` as below

```
gcc -fPIC -shared B.c -o libb.so -la
```

Now I created a binary which is calling `B()` that is defined in `b.so`

```
gcc mybin.c -o mybin -lb
```

gcc is checking for every symbol in b.so and throws error saying `A()` is not defined.

```
gcc mybin.c -o mybin -lb -la
```

The above works but I had to link mybin with `a.so` even though it is not directly related to `a.so`. My requirement is that if `b.so` is properly linked with `a.so`, linking **mybin** with just `b.so` should work.

Is this possible ??

Comment: `linking mybin with just a.so should work.` i hope you mean `b.so`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When linking the executable the linker wants to know that the libraries needed by `libb.so` exist so it can check they resolve any undefined references in `libb.so`

The linker looks for the required libraries in the usual places, so if that wouldn't find `liba.so` then you can tell the linker where to look by using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` as shown by another answer, or by using the linker option that exists specifically for this purpose, [`-rpath-link`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.24/ld/Options.html#index-link_002dtime-runtime-library-search-path-219)

```
gcc mybin.c -o mybin -lb -Wl,-rpath-link=.
```

(The `-Wl,` prefix is how you tell GCC to pass an option to the linker, which is needed for linker options that GCC doesn't know about directly.)

Alternatively, you can tell the linker to allow undefined symbols in `libb.so` in which case it doesn't try to find `liba.so` to resolve the reference to `A()`, and trusts that you'll link correctly and ensure the library is available at run-time. That is done with the [`--allow-shlib-undefined`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.24/ld/Options.html#index-g_t_002d_002dallow_002dshlib_002dundefined-192) option:

```
gcc mybin.c -o mybin -lb -Wl,--allow-shlib-undefined
```

However, it's generally better to let the linker check that all symbols are defined, and tell it how to find the required libraries, as it finds real problems sooner.

The `-rpath-link` option *only* tells the linker where to look for additional shared libraries, it has no visible effect on the linked executable (i.e. it doesn't record the path to the library in the executable anywhere). Another alternative is to create `libb.so` so that it contains the knowledge of how to find `liba.so` embedded within it. That is done with the `-rpath` linker option, e.g. if `liba.so` is in `/some/path` you could do:

```
gcc -fPIC -shared B.c -o libb.so -la -Wl,-rpath=/some/path
```

This puts a `DT_RPATH` tag in `libb.so` and the linker will use that to find its dependencies:

```
readelf -d libb.so  | fgrep RPATH
 0x000000000000000f (RPATH)              Library rpath: [/some/path]
```

Now you can link the executable without needing any knowledge of `liba.so`, the linker will see that `libb.so` needs `liba.so` and will use the RPATH to find it:

```
gcc mybin.c -o mybin -lb
```

This works fine if the path `/some/path/liba.so` is fixed, but it might not be true that the library is found in the same location during development and after your executable is deployed. In that case you can still use `-rpath-link` for the executable to tell the linker where to look for it during linking, and rely on the RPATH to find it at run-time. Or you can use the special string `$ORIGIN` in the RPATH which the dynamic linker expands to the location of the object containing the RPATH, e.g. if `liba.so` and `libb.so` are always in the same directory, you can link `libb.so` like this (note the quotes to prevent the shell expanding `$ORIGIN`):

```
gcc -fPIC -shared B.c -o libb.so -la '-Wl,-rpath=$ORIGIN'

readelf -d libb.so  | fgrep RPATH
 0x000000000000000f (RPATH)              Library rpath: [$ORIGIN]
```

Comment: Great answer. Is it possible to use -rpath-link while creating libb.so (linking liba.so to it) and create 'mybin' with just 'gcc mybin.c -o mybin -lb'

Comment: @tez, I've updated my answer. In short, you use `-rpath` for that, `-rpath-link` just adds directories to the search path while linking, whereas `-rpath` records directories in the executable/library

Answer (score 2):

The missing bit was the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.
gcc -fPIC -shared a.c -o liba.so
gcc -fPIC -shared b.c -o libb.so -la
gcc mybin.c -o mybin -lb -L.
```

The reason `-L` does not work seems it that this flag it used to « Add directory dir to the list of directories to be searched **for -l** » , see the [GCC doc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.2/gcc/Directory-Options.html#Directory-Options). And `libba.so` is not specified in a `-l`.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps:

```
gcc -fPIC -shared a.c -o liba.so
gcc -fPIC -shared b.c -o libb.so
gcc mybin.c -o mybin -lb -la -L.    # -L to look for the directory to load .so files

Then make sure you do:
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=<your_directory>
```

You need to have liba.so and libb.so mentioned in gcc mybin.c -o mybin -lb -la -L. as the function A() needs to be loaded at runtime. b.so IS NOT LINKED with a.so. Linking happens that runtime in shared library. They are compiled and any reference to functions or extern variables are not resolved.

If you want to include b.so but not a.so then compile the b as static library thereby it loads a into its binary. And then when you compile mybin you will only need b.lib

Comment: I'm really sorry but is that the solution OP asked for?

Comment: @Romaan My question is how to create 'mybin' without linking it to a.so

Comment: AH! Thanks for clearing that @tez, you need to have liba.so and libb.so mentioned in `gcc mybin.c -o mybin -lb -la -L. ` as the function A() needs to be loaded at runtime. b.so IS NOT LINKED with a.so. Linking happens that runtime in shared library. They are compiled and any reference to functions or extern variables are not resolved.

Comment: If you want to include b.so but not a.so then compile the b as static library thereby it loads a into its binary. And then when you compile mybin you will only need b.lib

Comment: @Romaan I hope now you understand the point of my comments. Nevertheless, thanks for the efforts. :-)